# como acceder a un campo mediante el metodo populate en mongoose

Tags: nodejs, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

estoy haciendo un sistema de notificaciones, este es mi modelo en mongoose:

```
notificaciones: [
  {
    de:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'usuario'}],
    motivo: {type: String, require: true},
    visto: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    date: {type: Date, default: new Date()}
  }
]
```

esto se esta guardando tal y como quería, mi problema es el siguiente, estoy trayendo los datos del usuario de la siguiente manera:

```
const usuario = await Usuario.findById(_id)
  .populate({path:'notificaciones'})
```

este método me devuelve todo, excepto un array, al mostrar por consola lo que me devuelve dicha consulta me devuelve esto:

```
notificaciones: [
  {
   de: [Array],
   visto: false,
   date: 2020-10-22T23:10:28.741Z,
   _id: 5f921c989bac890454708bc2,
   motivo: 'ah comenzado a seguirte.'
  }
]
```

lo que necesito es que en el campo `de` me muestre el array con los datos del usuario, pero solo me muestra `[Array]` y no lo que pretendo, ayuda por favor

Comment: ¿Y qué muestra por consola si escribes `notificaciones.forEach(notif => { console.log(notif.de); });`? O mejor aún, ¿qué te muestra si haces `console.dir(notificaciones);`?

Comment: en que parte del código dices agregarlo?

Comment: Cuando obtienes el documento de usuario, puedes hacer lo siguiente para ver en consola lo que tiene dicho `array`:  `usario.notificaciones.forEach(notif => { console.dir(notif.de); });`. Saludos

Comment: me muestra muchos datos, pero en ningún lado veo los datos del usuario de dicho id que se encuentra en el  array

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar cómo es tu esquema de datos?

Comment: agregue solamente una referencia al campo notificaciones, lo agregare a la pregunta